# Don't expand div across the edge of the screen

Tags: html, css

I have this page that shows alot of information in a table. One part of the table uses css to show additional information in a popup div. This works fine as long as the information is minimal. When there's a lot of text in the table it expands to the righ past the edge of the screen and becomes more or less unreadable. I can't disclose the information in the table because of security reasons, but I've uploaded an obfuscated image to imgur.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghm89.png

```css
/* version 2 */

a.memberinfo {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a.memberinfo b {
  display: none;
}
a.memberinfo:hover {
  border: 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 500;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-color: #000;
}
a.memberinfo:hover b {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: -25px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: #ffffee;
}
```

```html
<a class="memberinfo" href="#">Info
     <b>
      <em class="outer"></em>
      <em class="inner"></em>
            
      <table>       
       <thead>
        <tr>
         <th nowrap>
          Name
         </th>
         <th nowrap>
          Send
         </th>
         <th nowrap>
          Receive
         </th>
         <th>
          Interval
         </th>
         <th>
          Timeout
         </th>
         <th>
          Type
         </th>
        </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
                   
        <tr>
         <td nowrap>
          Name
         </td>
         <td nowrap>
          Senddata Senddata Senddata Senddata Senddata Senddata Senddata Senddata Senddata Senddata Senddata Senddata Senddata Senddata Senddata Senddata Senddata Senddata Senddata 
         </td>
         <td nowrap>
          Receive data
         </td>
         <td nowrap>
          1
         </td>
         <td nowrap>
          1
         </td>
         <td nowrap>
          TTYPE_HTTP
         </td>
        </tr>     
       </tbody>
      </table>
     </b>
</a>
```

Edit, here's a fiddle that shows the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/xp2xfbw6

I wish for the div to expand to the edge of the screen, but not further. If it needs to expand more I want it to expand to the left instead. I wish to avoid wrapping the text for readability reasons.

I really hope this explanation is clear enough. Otherwise, please let me know what's unclear and I'll try to answer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: then you should not use `position: absolute` find some other way..

Comment: When I copy it to jsfiddle, it expands over the entire viewport window, and is sticking out on both sides. What do you want to happen then? I can only see two solutions, and one of them is wrapping. The other one is hiding text that is too long, and replace the last content with elipsis...

Comment: Just realized that it is not centered in fact, it just looked like that. The <a> - info tag was just completely left adjusted, and so the popup was a little more left, and then outside the viewport...

Comment: Something like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/xp2xfbw6/

Comment: Exactly, the HTML above was aligned to the left since the popup link was not in a table.

Answer (score 2):

If the min/max suggested answer from Scor3keeper works for your needs, that is probably a better answer. Here is a more pinpointed (complicated) way of doing it, that might be even more precisely what you are looking for.

However, I have had a similar issue a short while ago, where I wanted a text box to appear vertically centered, inline with the vertically stacked list element that was clicked. However, if the text in the textbox was to long, and the box was expanding over, or under the desired area, it should be moved to the point where the top/bottom of the box was aligned with the bottom of the last list element.

I solved this in javascript/jquery:

```
$('div.myclass').click(function() {
        $('div.myclass').removeClass('selected');
        var $this = $(this);
        var $box = $("#contentdescription > div.arrow_box");
        $this.addClass('selected');
        var relativeTop = $($this).closest('#listcontainer').position().top;
        var offsetTop = $($this).position().top;
        var height = $this.height();
        var centerY = offsetTop + height / 2;       
        var html = $($this).data('content');   
        if(html.length > 0){
            $($box)
            .text(html)
            .show();
        } else {
            $($box)
            .text("No description found for this element")
            .show();
        }

        var topLimit = $('div.list-element:nth-of-type(1)').offset().top - relativeTop;
        var bottomLimit = $('div.list-element:last-of-type').offset().top + $('div.list-element:last-of-type').height() - relativeTop;
        var boxTop = centerY - ($box.height() / 2);

        //if the calculated top Point of the box, is not above the set limit, place the box there.
        if(boxTop > topLimit){
            $($box).css({
                top: boxTop 
            });
        } else {
            //otherwise, place it at the top limit
            $($box).css({
                top: topLimit 
            });
        }

        var boxBottom = $box.offset().top + $box.height() - relativeTop;

        //The box may still be sticking out underneath the bottom limit of the frame. If it does, adjust it to fit inside.
        if(boxBottom > bottomLimit){
            var newTop = bottomLimit -$box.height()
            $($box).css({
                top: newTop
            });
        }            

    });
```

I'm sure this can be refined into working horizontally. Bear in mind that this will not solve issues of the div being wider than the actual width of the browser window.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'm a javascript iliterate however so perhaps I need to figure out another way to show the information other than a popup.

Comment: I'm pretty impressed that you can do stuff like you showed us in HTML/CSS, and still be a javaScript iliterate! I just started learning web development about 18 months ago, and learning HTML, CSS and JavaScript went hand in hand.

Comment: Thanks for those kind words. I'm a network technician, not a coder. So I copy quite a lot and modify where I can (or understand). :)

Answer (score 1):

Set a min/max-width to a div container for the table and add overflow-x:auto;
This will causes a scroll bar to appear when the table goes out of bounds.

You could also format the table to go downwards instead of across.

Comment: Problem with scrollbars is that this is a popup triggered when the mouse hovers. As soon as I remove the mouse the popup (and scrollbars) disappears. Expanding the table downwards (I assume you mean transposing?) could also have been an option if not for the fact that I sometimes need to have multiple entries in the popup table which would make me face the same problem again.